# warnings in react.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a react.js beginner, and currently I'm doing a currency project, the functionality of the converter works well, but I got some error and warnings. Not really sure how to fix this.
Here are the following errors and warnings.

Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string. index.js:1 
at input
at div
at CurrencyRow
at App

The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

```
//App.js
function App() {
    const [currencyOption,setCurrencyOption] = useState([])
    const [fromCurrency,setFromCurrency] = useState()
    const [toCurrency,setToCurrency] = useState()
    const [exchangeRate,setExchangeRate] = useState()
    const [amount,setAmount] = useState(1)
    const [amountInFrom,setAmountInFrom] = useState(true)

    let fromAmount,toAmount
    if (amountInFrom){
        fromAmount = amount
        toAmount = fromAmount * exchangeRate
        
    }else{
        toAmount = amount
        fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate
    }

    useEffect ( ()=> {
        fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(response=>{
                const firstCurrency = Object.keys(response.rates)[0]
                setCurrencyOption([response.base,...Object.keys(response.rates)])
                setFromCurrency(response.base)
                setToCurrency(firstCurrency)
                setExchangeRate(response.rates[firstCurrency])
        })
    
    },[])

    useEffect ( ()=> {
        if (fromCurrency!=null && toCurrency!=null && fromCurrency!=="EUR")
        {
            fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
                .then(response=>response.json())
                .then(response=>{
                    
                    const resultCurrency = response.rates[toCurrency]/response.rates[fromCurrency]
                    setExchangeRate(resultCurrency)
                    
            })
        }
        else if (fromCurrency!=null && toCurrency!=null) 
        {
            fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
                .then(response=>response.json())
                .then(response=>{

                    setExchangeRate(response.rates[toCurrency])

                })
        }
    
    },[fromCurrency,toCurrency])


    function changeFromAmount(event) {
        
        setAmount(event.target.value)
        setAmountInFrom(true)
    }
    function changeToAmount(event) {
        
        setAmount(event.target.value)
        setAmountInFrom(false)
    }

    
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Convert</h1>
            <CurrencyRow 
                currencyOption = {currencyOption} 
                selectedCurrency = {fromCurrency} 
                onChangeCurrency = {event=>setFromCurrency(event.target.value)}
                amount = {fromAmount}
                changeAmount = {changeFromAmount}
            />
            <p className="equal">=</p>
            <CurrencyRow 
                currencyOption = {currencyOption} 
                selectedCurrency = {toCurrency} 
                onChangeCurrency = {event=>setToCurrency(event.target.value)}
                amount = {toAmount}
                changeAmount = {changeToAmount}
            /> 
        </>
    )

}

export default App
```

```
function CurrencyRow(props) {
    const {
        currencyOption,
        selectedCurrency,
        onChangeCurrency,
        amount,
        changeAmount
    } = props
    
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" className="input" value = {amount} onChange = {changeAmount}/>
            <select value = {selectedCurrency} className="option" onChange={onChangeCurrency}>
                {currencyOption.map(option=>(<option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>))}
                
            </select>
        </div>
    )

}
export default CurrencyRow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting `NaN` because your `exchangeRate` state has no initial value, so, at first render, the app tries to multiply `amount` by `undefined` that leads to `NaN` as the result

You need either to set initial value for `exchangeRate` or prevent calculation if not all operands are given